# Test Error of Binary Logit Model

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Consider the logistic regression model, where $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,\Sigma)$ and unkown parameter $\theta\in \mathbb{R}^d$. Furthermore for the random variable $Y\in \{-1,1\}$ we have
$$P(Y=y|X,\theta)=\frac{1}{1+\exp(-yX^T\theta)}$$
where $y\in \{-1,1\}$.

Let's assume that we have estimated $\theta$ by $\hat{\theta}$ and we are interested in calculating the following error probability:
$$P(Y\neq \hat{Y})=P(Y=1,\hat{Y}=-1)+P(Y=-1,\hat{Y}=1)$$

How can we calculate this generalization error?

Comment: How is $\hat{Y}$ defined? And is $\hat{\theta}$ obtained from $Y$ or are they independent?

Comment: $\hat{\theta}$ is independent from $Y$. Given $X$ and $\hat{\theta}$, if $X^T\hat{\theta}>0$ then $\hat{Y}=1$ otherwise $\hat{Y}=-1$.

Comment: Are you sure $\hat{\theta}$ is independent of $Y$? If so, then the probability reduces to $P(Y=1)P(X^\top \hat{\theta} > 0) + P(Y=-1) P(X^\top \hat{\theta} \le 0)$.

Comment: $\hat{\theta}$ is independent of $Y$, but the expression you wrote is wrong. Because $Y$ depends on $X$ and hence on $X^T\hat{\theta}$.

Comment: My mistake, I forgot that $X$ is also random.